# Easy way to write standard basis for $F^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field. The vector space $F^n=\{(a_1,\ldots,a_n):a_i\in F\}$ has a standard basis, where each of the vectors in the basis are $(1,0,\ldots,0)$, $(0,1,\ldots,0)$ and so on. Right now, I am writing this basis as
$$ B=\{(e_1,\ldots,e_n)\mid e_i=1 \text{ for some }i\in \{1,\ldots,n\},\,e_j=0\text{ for }j\neq i\}.$$
I don't want to just write
$$ B=\{(1,0,\ldots,0),(0,1,0,\ldots,0),\ldots,(0,\ldots,0,1)\} $$
even though that is easier -- to me, it looks somewhat ugly. Is there a more simple or succinct way to write this? Maybe using clever set theory notation?

Comment: You can also write $\{(\delta_{i,1},\dots, \delta_{i,n}) : i\in\{1,\dots,n\}\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would establish a notation for its elements, such as: $e^j$, where $$e^j_i=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }i=j\\ 0&\text{if }i\ne j\end{cases}.$$

Then I would call the basis $\mathcal C=\{e^j\,:\, 1\le j\le n\}$, though I might prefer $\mathcal C=\{e^j\}_{1\le j\le n}$ depending on whether or not I want to stress on the fact that basis should be functions, and not sets.